# show that $[f]_{B_1}$ is congruent to $[f]_{B_2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

> Let $f$ be a bilinear from on $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $$f(u,v)=2u_1v_1-3u_1v_2+u_2v_2,\quad u=(u_1,u_2),v=(v_1,v_2)$$ 
>   $(i)$ Find the matrices $[f]_{B_1}$ and $[f]_{B_2}$ relative to the bases $B_1=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ and $B_2=\{(2,1),(1,-1)\}$, respectively.
>   $(ii)$ Hence show that $[f]_{B_1}$ is congruent to $[f]_{B_2}$.

I manage to do $(i)$. And find the matrices 
$$[f]_{B_1}=\begin{pmatrix}2 &-1\\2 &0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad [f]_{B_2}=\begin{pmatrix}3 &9\\0 &6 \end{pmatrix}$$ But seems those matrices are not symmetric I don't know how to get any decomposition $[f]_{B_1}=P^T[f]_{B_2}P($in order to show congruent$)$.
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

---

Using @Trevor Gunn comment,
$$[f]_{B_2}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}}_{\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\ 2&-1\end{pmatrix}=P^T}[f]_{B_1}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}}_{\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}=P}$$ it seems lot of calculation needed to find those $P^T$ and $P$. Any easier approach do exist$?$

Comment: In general, if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are both written in terms of the standard basis, then to compute the change of basis matrix, you have to do $[B_1]^{-1}[B_2]$ or you have to do it "by inspection." In this case, $[B_1]$ represents a row operation so it takes almost no calculation to figure out what $[B_1]^{-1}[B_2]$ is: you just subtract the second row of $[B_2]$ from the first.

Comment: This is also why it is easy to do it by inspection. If $B_1$ and $B_2$ were more complicated, in particular if $B_1$ were not triangular, then it would be a lot more difficult to do the calculation by inspection. And, in fact, you'd ultimately have to compute $[B_1]^{-1}[B_2]$, no matter how you think about doing the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let T be a linear operator such that $T(u_i)=v_i$. The matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $B_1$, $$T(1,0)=(2,1)=(1)(1,0)+(1)(1,1)$$ $$T(1,1)=(1,-1)=(2)(1,0)+(-1)(1,1)$$ Therefore, coefficient matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $B_1$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&-1\end{pmatrix}$ Now the transition matrix $P$, $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\2&-1\end{pmatrix}^T=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}=P$$ Can you go from here$?$

Answer (score 1):

The matrices are not symmetric because $f$ is not symmetric.

For (ii), it is perhaps helpful to think about $[f]_B$ where $B$ is the standard basis. We have

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}[f]_B \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} &= 2,&
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}[f]_B \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} &= -1 \\ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}[f]_B \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} &= 2,&
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}[f]_B \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} &= 0.
\end{align}

So maybe you can see why

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^\top [f]_B \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = [f]_{B_1}. $$

If you can figure this out, you should be able to finish (ii).

Comment: What I understand is I need the coordinate matrix of $B_2$ w.r.t $B_1$ And follow yours idea, isn't it$?$ $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{4}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}2&-1\\ 2&0\end{pmatrix}                    \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\ \frac{4}{3}&-\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}\neq \begin{pmatrix}3&9\\ 0&6\end{pmatrix}$$ Where am I wrong$?$ @Trevor Gunn

Comment: @NajmunNahar Let $[B_i]$ be the matrix of $B_i$ in the standard basis. Then you substitute $[f]_B = [B_1]^{-\top} [f]_{B_1} [B_1]^{-1}$ into $[f]_{B_2} = [B_2]^\top [f]_B [B_2]$.

Comment: I got it and update my question @Trevor Gunn